# Foursquare API Error code 410

Tags: php, api, oauth, foursquare

My code which i have been using until today, started to fail without anything i've done. i am receiving it with 401 error code. What might be a problem ?

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'EpiFoursquareException' with message '{"meta":{"code":410,"errorType":"param_error","errorDetail":"The Foursquare API no longer supports requests that do not pass in a version parameter. For more details see https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/versioning"},

My code: http://pastebin.com/VwmUrfMX

Answer (score 7):

This is just assuming that you are doing venue search.You need to pass the version number in the current date format(YYYYMMDD).

for example:

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=40.7,-74&client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&v=YYYYMMDD

I hope it helps you:)

Comment: About the version parameter: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/configuration/versioning

Answer (score 3):

You need to add parameter `v` which represents the version of the API you are expecting.

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/configuration/versioning

> Versioning is controlled by the `v` parameter, which is a date that represents the “version” of the API for which you expect from Foursquare.
>
> All API requests require a version parameter. This gives developers control over the time period in which to call our continuously updated API. In order to stay up to date with the latest changes, we recommend updating your version as often as possible.

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search
  ?client_id=CLIENT_ID
  &client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET
  &ll=40.7,-74
  &query=sushi
  &v=YYYYMMDD
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the foursquare API, but I guess it probably has to do literally with the error you received

> The Foursquare API no longer supports requests that do not pass in a version parameter.

So, if I am not very wrong you just need to update `EpiFoursquare.php` with the new version [from git](https://github.com/jmathai/foursquare-async/blob/master/EpiFoursquare.php) which seems to be about right as the last commit is:

> **meza** *3 months ago* 'added new api versioning support'

Comment: I upgrade the file and the error is gone. but check-in's still does not come.

Comment: Then I fear that's an unrelated error, check which version of the file you had, maybe there were other unrelated non backward compatible commits on the  github File.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution just verify link again

code for venue details

```
public static  string  GenerateURL(double latitude, double longitude)
{
    return string.Format(
        Constants.VENUE_SEARCH,
        latitude,
        longitude,
        Constants.CLIENT_ID,
        Constants.CLIENT_SECRET,
        DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
    );
}
```

and link for api will be:

```
public const string VENUE_SEARCH = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll={0},{1}&client_id={2}&client_secret={3}&v={4}";
```